# Flutter adding tile layer to current layer

Tags: flutter, mobile, tile

I am developing an app that shows ski pistes and lifts. I am able get those maps separately:

For base map (which is my main map)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

class SkiMapSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const SkiMapSection({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: new FlutterMap(
        options: new MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(40.58, 31.78),
          minZoom: 10.0,
        ),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate:
                "https://snowmap.fast-sfc.com/base_snow_map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", 
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For pistes and lifts I need to change **urlTemplate:** to the https://snowmap.fast-sfc.com/pistes/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

However my aim is to print lift url onto the basemap. How can I achieve that? Can flutter do that?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally by setting background color to transparent of piste layer I am able to show them at the same time.

```
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

class SkiMapSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const SkiMapSection({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: new FlutterMap(
        options: new MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(40.58, 31.78),
          minZoom: 10.0,
        ),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate:
                "https://snowmap.fast-sfc.com/base_snow_map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            //change base_snow_map to pistes
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          ),
          TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate:
                  "https://snowmap.fast-sfc.com/pistes/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
              //change base_snow_map to pistes
              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```